# Prompt Monad in Purescript

Tags: monads, existential-type, purescript

I'm working through the definition of `Prompt` and its `Bind` instance described [here](http://joeysmandatory.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/explaining-prompt-monad-with-simpler.html) and was trying to figure out how this would look in Purescript.

I am using [`Purescript.Exists`](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-exists) for the existential type. My defintion is then:

```
data PromptAskF p r a
  = PromptAskF (p a) (a -> Prompt p r)

type PromptAsk p r = Exists (PromptAskF p r)

data Prompt p r
  = Ask (PromptAsk p r)
  | Answer r 

instance bindPrompt :: Bind (Prompt p) where
  bind (Answer x) k = k x
  bind (Ask ask) k = ???
```

I am stuck on writing the `Ask` case in the `Bind` instance and, in particular, I'm very confused about the types when working with `runExists`.

How should I write this instance?

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
data PromptAskF p r a
  = PromptAskF (p a) (a -> Prompt p r)

type PromptAsk p r = Exists (PromptAskF p r)

mapPA
  :: forall p r r'
   . (forall a. (a -> Prompt p r) -> (a -> Prompt p r'))
  -> PromptAsk p r
  -> PromptAsk p r'
mapPA f = runExists \(PromptAskF req cont) -> mkExists $ PromptAskF req (f cont)

data Prompt p r
  = Ask (PromptAsk p r)
  | Answer r

instance functorPrompt :: Functor (Prompt p) where
  map f (Answer r) = Answer (f r)
  map f (Ask ask) = Ask $ mapPA (map (map f)) ask

instance applyPrompt :: Apply (Prompt p) where
  apply = ap

instance applicativePrompt :: Applicative (Prompt p) where
  pure = Answer

instance bindPrompt :: Bind (Prompt p) where
  bind (Answer x) k = k x
  bind (Ask ask) k = Ask $ mapPA (\cont ans -> cont ans >>= k) ask

instance monadPrompt :: Monad (Prompt p)
```

The `mapPA` function is a convenience for updating the `PromptAskF` continuation without having to repeatedly `runExists` / `mkExists`.

Comment: Hi Gary, thank you for your answer. This makes sense to me but not, apparently, to the type checker! I'm getting the following error :         `Error found:
in module Main
at  line 26, column 1 - line 30, column 26

  A type variable has escaped its scope.

in the expression (flip runExists) ask
in value declaration bindPrompt`

Comment: I've just updated the answer to include the full implementation to ensure it actually typechecks this time! That error message can be quite difficult to deal with sometimes, in this case it was due to `flip`ping `runExists`, but even after that there was some weirdness (couldn't put the lambda in a `where` without it arising). Moving it out to `runPA` makes it a little easier to read, and providing the explicit type signature for the mapping function helps avoid other potential skolem escape issues.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for taking the time to update. This is actually clearer to me than the Haskell implementation now, thanks to the explicit rank-n types.